# Can't Figure Out Correct Protractor Syntax

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm building Protractor tests and am seeking to refactor some code.

This line of code works fine:

```
element.all(by.css('div.modal-content ly-input input')).first().sendKeys("Workflow 1");
```

Then I tried doing this:

```
 var name = element(by.css('div.modal-content ly-input'));

 element(name).all(by.css('input')).sendKeys("Workflow 1")
```

There is something wrong with this last line of code, as I'm getting a `"Failed: Invalid locator" error.`

Might anyone know how I can introduce the `name` variable and use it in the last line of code?

Robert

Comment: you cannot use `element(name).all(by.css('input')).sendKeys("Workflow 1")` when your `var name` is `element(by.css('div.modal-content ly-input'));
` instead it should be `var name = by.css('div.modal-content ly-input')` as a locator

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I finally figured it out:
    name.all(by.css('input')).sendKeys("Workflow 1")

Answer (score 0):

I see you figured it out. Here is how I write my sendKeys in order to have more clarity when I read my code:

```
var name = 'Workflow 1';    
var input = element.all(by.css('div.modal-content ly-input'));

input.first().sendKeys(name);

// or if you have multiple inputs in that element above
var workflowData = {
   name: 'Workflow 1',
   description: 'a workflow',
   type: 'simple'
}    
var input = element.all(by.css('div.modal-content ly-input'));

input.get(0).sendKeys(workflowData.name);
input.get(1).sendKeys(workflowData.description);
input.get(2).sendKeys(workflowData.type);
```